# Reimt ein Wort sich auf sich selbst?

Tags: poetry

Ich diskutierte gerade mit Arbeitskollegen über Wörter, die sich auf nichts reimen, als die Frage aufkam, ob sich ein Wort denn nicht auf sich selbst reime.
Reimt sich Pfirsich beispielsweise auf Pfirsich?

Ich konnte ich keiner Definition von Reim, die ich las, etwas finden, das dagegen spricht. Vielleicht findet sich hier jemand, der Aufschluss geben kann.

Comment: Da man in diesem Fall von _identischem Reim_ spricht (und nicht von _identischem Nichtreim_), ist es wohl ein Reim. Der identische Reim ist aber nicht sehr verbreitet, er klingt seltsam und oft gar nicht wie ein Reim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es gibt angeblich rund 90 reimfreie deutsche Wörter, wie z.B. Kiosk, Mensch, Pfirsich usw. Das sind Wörter, zu denen es kein *anderes, nicht-zusammengesetztes* Wort gibt, das mit diesem Wort einen *reinen* Reim bildet. Und zu dieser speziellen Klasse von Wörtern gehört auch *selbst*.

Entscheidend bei dieser Definition sind die Begriffe **anderes Wort**, **nicht zusammengesetzt** und **reiner Reim**.

**Identischer Reim**
Dass sich ein Wort auf sich selbst reimt, ist trivial. Entweder man behauptet, dass es sich bei diesem Sachverhalt um *keinen* Reim handelt, oder man verwendet dafür den Begriff »identischer Reim«.

**Zusammengesetzt**
Das trifft natürlich auch auf zusammengesetzte Wörter zu, deren letzter Bestandteil dasselbe eigenständig existierende Wort ist. So sind »Orgel«, »Kirchenorgel« und »Rockorgel« selbstverständlich drei verschiedene Wörter, die sich alle untereinander reimen. Aber weil es in dieser Reimgruppe nur ein einziges nicht zusammengesetztes Wort gibt (»Orgel«), gilt dieses einzelne nichtzusammengesetzte Wort als reimfrei.

**Reiner Reim**
Auch wichtig im Fall der reimfreien Wörter ist der Begriff des reinen Reims. Zwei Wörter bilden einen reinen Reim, wenn sie mit *derselben* phonetischen (also gesprochenen) Endsilbe enden. Wenn die Endsilbe über einen konsonantischen Silbenschwanz verfügt, genügt auch eine Übereinstimmung ab dem Silbenkern (z.B. »rot« - »lot«).

Das ist zu unterscheiden vom unreinen Reim (Bei Schiller findet man: »Höh'n« - »steh'n«), den man auch auf reimfreie Wörter bilden kann. Dabei ähneln sich die gesprochenen Endsilben der beiden Wörter mehr oder weniger, ohne phonetisch identisch zu sein.

**Reimgruppe**
Die Wörter, die untereinander paarweise einen reinen Reim ergeben, bilden zusammen eine Reimgruppe. Aus dieser Definition folgt, dass die Eigenschaft »reiner Reim« eine partitionierende Eigenschaft ist. Das heißt, durch diese Eigenschaft werden alle existierenden Wörter Gruppen zugeteilt, mit der Eigenschaft, dass jedes Wort zu genau einer einzigen Reimgruppe gehört (also nicht zu null und nicht zu zwei oder mehr). Und wenn in einer Reimgruppe nur ein einziges nichtzusammengesetztes Wort ist, ist dieses Wort per Definition *reimfrei*.

Comment: reimt sich dann nicht lieblich auf Pfirsich?